# string index out of range when returning a list of tuples

Tags: python

Let me just apologize for the title, mods feel free to edit it to something you feel is more appropriate. I struggled finding a more fitting title.

I have an exercise I'm working on. I'm to implement two classes, Country, and CountryDirectory respectively. The exercise deals with manipulating this directory of countries, through methods used to add/delete countries, to updating the population and areas of arbitrary countries, etc.

We are given a driver program to test our methods. There is one method in particular, "populationDensityFilter," that is giving me issues. This method serves to determine which countries fall within a chosen interval. More specifically, it takes min and max as parameters for a population density range. It should return a list of countries that have a density that falls within the range. It should return a list of pairs, where each pair is a country name and a population density.  The list should be descending order from the highest density to
the lowest. If nothing falls within the range, it should return an empty list.

My code works in correctly returning the countries that fall within a given range, however, when paired with the given test method it returns the Error. I believe  its because the test method is expecting a tuple containing, the country in index 0, and density in index 1. I appreciate any help, thanks.

There are two text files that are read:

continent.txt

```
China,Asia
United States of America,North America
Brazil,South America
Japan,Asia
Canada,North America
Indonesia,Asia
Nigeria,Africa
Mexico,North America
Egypt,Africa
France,Europe
Italy,Europe
South Africa,Africa
South Korea,Asia
Colombia,South America
```

data.txt

```
Country|Population|Area
China|1,339,190,000|9,596,960.00
United States of America|309,975,000|9,629,091.00
Brazil|193,364,000|8,511,965.00
Japan|127,380,000|377,835.00
Canada|34,207,000|9,976,140.00
Indonesia|260,581,100|1,809,590.97
Nigeria|186,987,563|912,134.45
Mexico|128,632,004|1,969,230.76
Egypt|93,383,574|1,000,000.00
France|64,668,129|541,656.76
Italy|59,801,004|300,000.00
South Africa|54,978,907|1,222,222.22
South Korea|50,503,933|98,076.92
Colombia|48,654,392|1,090,909.09
```

Here's my code:

```
# My code
    def populationDensityFilter(self, min, max):
        for element in self._catalogue:
            if self._catalogue[element].getPopulationDensity() >= min and self._catalogue[element].getPopulationDensity() <= max:
                print(element) # should be return

# Given test method that my code has to work in conjunction with.
def testDensityFilter(countryDirectory):
    print()
    low = input(" Enter lower bound for population density: ")
    low = float(low.strip())
    up = input(" Enter  upper bound for population density: ")
    up = float(up.strip())
    abc = countryDirectory.populationDensityFilter(low,up)
    if len(abc) == 0:
        print("  Nothing in that range found.")
    else:
        print("  Countries with density in this range:")
        for x in abc:
            print(x[0] + ", " + "density = "+ str(x[1]))

def main():
    cd = countryDirectory('data.txt','continent.txt')
    testDensityFilter(cd)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `populationDensityFilter`:

```
results = []
for element in self._catalogue:
    pop = self._catalogue[element].getPopulationDensity()
    if pop >= min and pop <= max:
        results.append((element, pop))
return results
```

As you've mentioned,

> I believe its because the test method is expecting a tuple containing,
>   the country in index 0, and density in index 1.

So you should assemble a list of `(country, density)` to return.